# Is it possible to read out the Uid of a NFC chip on ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, nfc

Is it possible to read out the Uid of a NFC chip on ios? I stumbled upon a post from 2017 that said Apple doesn't allow it and I also only get an empty array when trying to get the Uid.
So is there any way to read the Uid and if not: will this be possible in the future? Because I don't see a reason why this shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Yes you can, using CoreNFC.

Comment: iOS 13 changes this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978507/reading-uids-of-nfc-cards-in-ios-13